Why does randomness sometimes lead to order?
I am learning about Schelling's Model of Segregation  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schelling%27s_model_of_segregation)
My understanding is as follows:

Consider a grid of cells where agents of two different types  A and B) are distributed.
Each cell $(i,j)$ in the grid can be in one of three states:

$$s_{ij} = \begin{cases} 
1 & \text{if occupied by type A} \\
-1 & \text{if occupied by type B} \\
0 & \text{if empty}
\end{cases}$$

For each agent, we define their neighborhood $N(i,j)$ as the set of cells within radius $r$ of their location.
The number of similar neighbors for an agent at position $(i,j)$ is:

$$S_{ij} = \sum_{(k,l) \in N(i,j)} \mathbb{1}(s_{ij} \cdot s_{kl} > 0)$$

The satisfaction ratio for an agent is defined as (where $|N(i,j)|$ is the total number of occupied cells in the neighborhood):

$$R_{ij} = \frac{S_{ij}}{|N(i,j)|}$$

An agent is satisfied if their satisfaction ratio exceeds some threshold $t$: $R_{ij} \geq t$

The game works as follows:

At each time step $t$, identify all unsatisfied agents where $R_{ij} < t$
Each unsatisfied agent moves to a random empty cell
Repeat until either:

All agents are satisfied ($R_{ij} \geq t$ for all occupied cells)
Or a maximum number of iterations is reached



The segregation index $\Psi$ for the entire grid can be calculated as (where $N$ is the total number of agents):
$$\Psi = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i,j} \mathbb{1}(R_{ij} \geq t)$$
Supposedly, with even low values of $t$ (like $t = 0.3$), the system tends to evolve toward highly segregated states (i.e. ordered): Random configurations of the grid supposedly always lead to ordered configurations

I am trying to understand : why does this behavior happen? is there some mathematical reason for this?
Or is the result trivial? E.g. satisfied agents don't move, an unsatisfied agents only move to areas where they will be satisfied. Therefore, the overall satisfaction of the grid will either stay constant or improve - but never get worse?
Can someone please help me understand this? Is there a mathematical proof for this?

In physics this is called "spontaneously broken symmetry". For large enough $t$ the system will evolve to something ordered (i.e. not homogeneous/symmetric), but what the ordered state looks like depends on the randomness, so it's still equally likely for a cell to be red or blue. The simplest model is the Ising model of the magnetization transition, where at low enough temperatures all the domains will mostly evolve to point in the same direction, resulting in a magnetized state (but it's random which direction they will all point).

Makes me think of "The Game of Life"

wow, thank you everyone for your replies! Is there a way to express this as a mathematical proof?

A related phenomenon is demonstrated by Galton's quincunx - the Wikipedia page has a nice video showing an example of randomness leading to order.

Intuitively, your process says the agents keep moving randomly until they find a group of agents of the same type.

see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey%27s_theorem
